# C# WinForm TabControl Formatting Issue

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tabcontrol

When programmatically adding controls to a tab control, I have been using the Form_Load event to create and embed things like datagridviews into my UI. I made a class that inherits from DataGridView

```
class DBDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    public DBDataGridView()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
        AllowUserToOrderColumns = false;
        AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
        RowHeadersVisible = false;
        AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
        ReadOnly = true;
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        TabStop = false;
    }
}
```

And I call it later in the Form_Load event like so

```
    private void MainDesignerForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DBDataGridView _DGV = new DBDataGridView();

        var listOfOverlays = new List<OverlaySelectionList>()
        {
            new OverlaySelectionList { Description = "Description 1", PartNumber = "123-R1"},
            new OverlaySelectionList { Description = "Description 2", PartNumber = "456-R1"}
        };
        var overlayList = new BindingList<OverlaySelectionList>(listOfOverlays);
        _DGV.DataSource = overlayList;
        Tab_Overlay.Controls.Add(_DGV);
        _DGV.ClearSelection();
    }
```

This gridview is on the THIRD tab of the TabControl, and everything works as expected except the ClearSelection(). No matter where I call it, it does not clear the initial row selection of the DGV. However, if I fire the same code block from a button ON the third tab, the formatting AND the ClearSelection() behave as expected.

What is causing this behavior?

Comment: Assuming `Tab_Overlay` is not the selected tab page, all its controls (including the DGV) are not visible (yes, `.Visible == false`) which causes `ClearSelection()` to not do its job. Try adding `yourTabControl.SelectedTab = Tab_Overlay;` before `_DGV.ClearSelection();`. Then, you can reset the selected tab afterward if needed.

Comment: TabPages sometimes don't fully update their layout. Maybe you can add code to the SelectedIndexChanged to fix it..

Comment: So, selecting the tab does in fact fix the issue (And I can always just set the selected tab back to the first tab for presentation sake) - What I don't understand though is why does property assignment work, but not the ClearSelection() when the tab is not visible?

Comment: Controls of TabPages that are not shown when the Parent Form is shown don't create their handles. So you can set properties that cache their values, but many methods that rely on the handle creation don't do anything (except setting/changing the value of some properties, if that's part of their behavior), since the .Net implementation always checks if the handle is created before actions that require a handle can be performed.

Comment: To note that a lot of WinForms Controls are based on Win32 Controls. Hence a number of standard actions are then performed by the underlying Win32 Control. PInvoking is required to perform many of these actions. You cannot PInvoke if you don't have a Handle.

Comment: Is there a way to tell if an action requires a Handler? For example, if I made a custom implementation that recreated the functionality of ClearSelection() in my inherited class and called MyClass.MyClearSelection(), would that still fail to execute?

Comment: You can force the handle creation, but you need to consider what are the implications, performace-wise. There's a reason why child Controls of TabPages of a TabControl don't create their handles. You can always check (`bool hasHandle = [Control].IsHandleCreated;`). Or force it as `_ = [Control].Handle;` or calling `CreateControl()` in specific contexts.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your input and helping solve the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to 41686d6564 and Jimi for the insight into the specifics on why this was happening.

Reiterating what they said in the comments: Assignment of properties appear to be cached regardless of whether the control they belong to is active or not (Hence why all the sizing and formatting properties were present at run time). However, actions that require a handle, like ClearSelection() require the control to be shown and active for the intended behavior to be observed.

Setting the selected tab to where the DataGridView before calling ClearSelection() was the solution (Or in my case, I had nested tabs, so I had to follow the tab tree to get to the specific tab that the DataGridView was on)

So now, part of the Load_Form logic is to check WHERE the control is located, make that tab active, THEN format and clear selections for each control that is being added. This allowed ClearSelection() to work as intended.